# "contentSizeForViewInPopover" - what does this do?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

This is both a question, and a solution.

I recently added a very simple UIViewController with a .xib to my iPad application, containing just a UIDatePicker and a UILabel, which I wish to display as a popup in my iPad app.

[image: Storyboard]

I added all of the relevant code to display this .xib as a popup.  There were no errors or warnings, my UIViewController class *was* set as the "Class" for this .xib, and both controls showed that they were linked to the *IBOutlets* in this particular file.

But, when I ran the app, the popup *would* appear perfectly well, but if I tried to access anything to do with these two controls, nothing would happen.

So, for example, the following code attempted to set the label's text, to change the UIDatePicker's mode...  and nothing would happen.  I tried breakpoints, the code WAS being  run, the controls did have a value (they weren't nil) but this code wouldn't do anything.  The UILabel's text wouldn't be changed, the DatePicker would continue to be in "Date & Time" mode, etc.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
        [self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(LabelChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        self.lblQuestion.text = @"Is this working...?";
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        self.datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Eventually - eventually - I added one line of code, to set the "contentSizeForViewInPopover":

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Without this line of code, the code-behind doesn't communicate
        // with the controls in this .xib
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.bounds.size;

        //  ... etc ...
```

...and suddenly, it worked beautifully.

[image]

So, my question is..  *why ?!*

What the heck does this one line of code do, which suddenly makes it so I *can* set my UILabel's text, and can talk to the UIDatePicker control...?

I'm very used to the quirks and crashes with XCode, but I'm baffled by why this suddenly made my code start to work.  I'm relieved that this quirk "only" wasted a couple of hours of my life...  and would like to understand the reason behind it.

Btw, this is with XCode 4.6.3, running on an iOS 6.1 SDK app for an iPad.

Comment: Default size for the popover displaying the controller.

Comment: Yeah, from it's name, I deduced what "contentSizeForViewInPopover" is supposed to do.  But without this line, the control was exactly the same size, still displayed as a popup, but my code couldn't access the values in it's controls.  THAT is my question.  Why would such a "default size" function completely affect the way the controls worked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outlets are connected when the nib is loaded. The nib is loaded when you access the controllers's view for the first time.

In other words, in your initializer all your outlets are nil. However, if you call `self.view`, your view gets loaded and outlets are connected. `contentSizeForViewInPopover` or `bounds.size` is irrelevant.

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.view; //this is enough
    ...
```

This is why you shouldn't put such code into initializer but into `viewDidLoad` instead.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.datePicker addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(LabelChange:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.lblQuestion.text = @"Is this working...?";
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    self.datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
}
```

Comment: Oh... I am so dumb.  Yup, you're absolutely right.  

Thank you.  
It makes sense now !!